# Why does my dialog box appear like this?

Tags: c++, dialog, window, box

I have created a simple dialog box in a resource file. When I try to spawn it using DialogBox(), the dialog appears but it looks like does not have a window. I don't know why this happens. Any advice?

It looks like this when running, as you can see there is no window. The check boxes, text and stuff don't have a background, and there is no title bar. Nothing.

[image]

And it should show up as this:

[image]

The code I use to spawn it is:

```
bool mostrarVentanaConfiguracion() {

    DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_DIAG_CONFIG), NULL, (DLGPROC)VentanaConfiguracion);
    return true;
}
```

This is the .rc file code:

```
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
ID_DIAG_CONFIG DIALOG 260, 200, 339, 203
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE
CAPTION "Configuración"
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{
    LTEXT           "Pulsar la combinación de teclas.", 0, 218, 18, 102, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    CONTROL         "", ID_CONF_MACRO, HOTKEY_CLASS, WS_TABSTOP, 136, 16, 77, 12, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        ID_CONF_INDICATIVO, 16, 16, 70, 12, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_REUNION, 14, 67, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de reuniones o 10-80 general.", 0, 28, 67, 125, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    GROUPBOX        "Configuración de los avisos", 0, 5, 36, 328, 142, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancelar", IDCANCEL, 220, 184, 49, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "Guardar\r\n", IDOK, 280, 184, 54, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_SEISADAM, 14, 80, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_CODIGOCINCO, 14, 92, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_CENTRALITA, 14, 105, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_REP_UNIDADES, 14, 117, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_PROPIO, 14, 129, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_PEDIDOS, 14, 141, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_PEDIDOS_SWAT, 14, 153, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_SIN_ASIG, 14, 165, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_PANICO, 187, 67, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_APOYO, 187, 79, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_HERIDO, 187, 91, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_ROBO_COCHE, 187, 103, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_ROBO_CASA, 187, 115, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_ROBO_NEG, 187, 127, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_PAPAFOX, 187, 139, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_ROBO_BANCO, 187, 151, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    AUTOCHECKBOX    "Check", ID_A_CUSTODIA, 187, 163, 8, 8, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Recibir notificaciones sonoras para...", 0, 14, 50, 117, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de CÓDIGO 6-ADAM.", 0, 28, 79, 100, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de CÓDIGO 5.", 0, 28, 91, 77, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de centralita roleados.", 0, 28, 103, 100, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... pedidos de reportes de unidades.", 0, 28, 115, 114, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos a mi propia unidad o nombre.", 0, 28, 127, 122, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de pedidos generales (10-32, 10-37...)", 0, 28, 139, 150, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de pedidos para SWAT", 0, 28, 151, 105, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de agentes sin asignación.", 0, 28, 163, 115, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de botón de pánico.", 0, 201, 67, 94, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de solicitud de apoyo (/ref)", 0, 201, 79, 115, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de herido.", 0, 201, 91, 62, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de robo de vehículo.", 0, 201, 103, 97, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de robo a vivienda. ", 0, 201, 115, 94, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de robo a negocio.", 0, 201, 127, 90, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de alarma de prisión federal.", 0, 201, 139, 119, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de robo a banco.", 0, 201, 151, 85, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "... avisos de sospechosos bajo custodia.", 0, 201, 163, 128, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    GROUPBOX        "Configuración del indicativo", 0, 7, 4, 114, 28, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    GROUPBOX        "Macro para desactivar el programa temporalmente", 0, 127, 4, 206, 28, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
}
```

Comment: It's not immediately clear what library you're using to generate the dialog box. You should probably clarify this.

Comment: I used ResEdit to create the resource file because VS2013 Express doesn't include a resource editor. I'm just using the standard Windows API to display de Dialog. I should mention that the application is a system tray app and it starts in the system tray with it's icon automatically, that's why the dialog does not have any parent window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already fixed it. I was returning true in the dialog procedure instead of false.

From MSDN:

"Typically, the dialog box procedure should return TRUE if it processed the message, and FALSE if it did not. If the dialog box procedure returns FALSE, the dialog manager performs the default dialog operation in response to the message."